# How to enable GlobalMethodsSecurity when unit test with MockMvc of standaloneSetup

Tags: spring-security, mockito, junit4, mockmvc

SpringSecurity's @PreAuthorize and @PostAuthorize is ignored when unit testing with MockMvc. But it's OK when access by browser of Postman while normally started the application

I am using Spring 4.3 and Spring security 4.2, not the spring boot. I am using `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup` to test the controller only. and don't want to use webAppContextSetup to involve the entire application to test.

After check the spring security's source code, I found that the Pre and PostAuthorize is checking by org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedPreInvocationAdvice and org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedPostInvocationAdvice. But the controller is not include by org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource.

I think this is caused by the controller is not initialized by Spring, so I try to register it to the BeanFactory, but it also fail.

Testing code:

```java
@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controllers)
                .setValidator(validator)
                .apply(springSecurity(filterChainProxy))
                .alwaysDo(print())
                .build();
}

public void itWillFailWhenUpdateOtherOrg() {
    CurrentUser user = new CurrentUser();
    user.setOrgId(1);
    user.setUsername("testuser");
    mockMvc.perform(put("/orgs/-1")
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content("{\"name\":\"RootOrg\",\"parent\":100}")
                .with(user(user))).andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    verify(orgService, never()).update(any());
}
```

Controller code:

```java
@PutMapping("/org/{id}")
@PreAuthorize("principal.orgId == #orgDO.parent")
public OrgDO update(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody OrgDO orgDO) {
}
```

When testing, the status code is 200, but not 403.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
Expected :403
Actual   :200
```

I expect the put request will fail and return status code 403, because of the `principal.orgId != #orgDO.parent`.

Be sure to NOT include all class to the Spring context, I just want to test the controller class.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

After few hours of digging here is why:
`MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup` normally get passed a controller instantiated manually (not with Spring and therefore not with AOP). Therefore the PreAuthorize is not intercepted and security check is skipped. You can therefore either @Autowire your controller and pass it to MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup (which maybe kind of defies the purpose of using standalone setup since it's alos create the rest controller...) or simply use a WebApplicationContext: MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup with an autowired WepAppContext.